# Reflexive verbs and their categorization

Tags: verbs

How would you categorize reflexive verbs?

Some verbs, e.g. *lavarsi*, are properly reflexive. For other verbs, e.g. *alzarsi*, the reflexive pronoun carries a different function.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? I am not sure I get the difference between *lavarsi* (= *lavare sé stessi*, as opposed to wash somebody or something else) and *alzarsi* (= *alzare sé stessi*, as opposed to raise somebody or something else).

Comment: @DaG Thanks for your answer. I kept the question vague on purpose to see what sort of input I could get. I am not sure if I would consider *alzarsi* equivalent to *lavarsi*, though.

Comment: Have you seen this?
http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-riflessivi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/
There is a classification of reflexive verbs (riflessivo diretto, indiretto, reciproco, mediale etc.) that might correspond to what you are looking for. Probably, in your examples, *lavarsi* is a *riflessivo diretto* while *alzarsi* is a *riflessivo mediale*.