# Issues with reflexive verbs and si passivante

Tags: grammar, english-comparison

I'll explain my current knowledge for context.

Given there is 3 main types of verbs, namely, action (transitive or intransitive), linking (e.g to be, to become), and modal (or helping verbs).

Firstly, I understand that we use the *si passivante* when talking impersonally about an action on a noun. For example, "*la porta si apre*" (the door opened). We do not know who opened it but certainly that the action occurred. Clearly the *si passivante* is only applicable to transitive verbs. Hence, Linking verbs do not have a *si passivante* form I'll explain why this point is relevant.

My first question is that is it necessarily true in Italian that reflexive forms of verbs are actually standalone verbs unlike in English? Furthermore does a verb change form when transformed into the reflexive? For example the verb *trovare* is a transitive verb however the reflexive form *trovarsi* which means roughly to be located is a linking verb (although I could be wrong).

In the sentence "L'Italia si trova in Europa" is this the *si passivante* form of "trovare" or the reflexive?

Hope my questions make sense, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! It's really a bit hard to me to understand your question. What do you mean with "a verb change form"?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but  many Italian verbs have transitive and intransitive uses. The verb "trovare" that you are mentioning can be transitive, but "trovarsi" is what is called a "verbo intransitivo pronominale", so it's intransitive.

Comment: Hi! Can you explain exactly what that means for trovarsi, what are the rules there? Also, can you explain the function of "si trova" in the sentence I wrote, is it si passivante or trovarsi?

Comment: Have you seen the other questions on this site on similar doubts? I have found this: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/can-si-passivante-be-constructed-with-null-subject-in-certain-contexts, but I'm sure there are more. Do they help to focus your problem?

Comment: @DaG I guess something I would like an answer to is an analysis on the verb "trovarsi" and an example of it in use. I would also like to see an example of trovare used in the si passivante.

Comment: The sentence "L'Italia si trova in Europa" is an example of use of intransitive pronominal "trovarsi" (what you call "reflexive form *trovarsi*" in the question). A way to see it is that you normally don't say "trovo l'Italia in Europa". You can say, for instance, "trovo molte conchiglie in questa spiaggia", so you can construct the sentence "si trovano molte conchiglie in questa spiaggia" as an example of "si passivante".

Comment: @Charo Thank-you! So is the subject "L'italia" in a sense acting on itself, in the first sentence?

Comment: I won't say "l'Italia" is acting on itself in this sentence: this is why "trovarsi" is a pronominal verb, but it isn't really a reflexive verb such as, for instance, "lavarsi".

Comment: @Luke Not all verbs in the reflexive voice have actually a reflexive meaning. I think we have somewhere on this site an answer with all the kind of reflexives that are there in Italian, some of them have very little to do with "reflecting" the action. Really, a better way of thinking of the reflexive voice is as the Italian version of the [mediopassive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediopassive_voice).

Comment: @DenisNardin: Do you mean [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1730)? Because, if it's this one, it was closed a lot of years ago.

Comment: Anyway, @Luke, I believe you should edit your question and try to focus it.

Comment: @DenisNardin Thank you for the link. However I'm still struggling to understand this type of verb, how can I  easily describe theses types and identify them?

Comment: @Charo yes I agree, my scope has got a lot narrower since discussing with you both.

Comment: This link http://grammatica.impariamoitaliano.com/2014/06/si-passivante.html has some examples about the *si passivante*, hope it helps.